# Can't Call resignFirstResponder from textFieldDidBeginEditing ? (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, first-responder

```
[myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
[myTextField resignFirstResonder];
```

When I do this `-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField` , it works. But when I use the same code inside `-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` , it does not work.

I am certain that it is calling `textFieldDidBeginEditing`. I have an `NSLog` inside the method and it is being called.

Comment: Why would you want the textField to resign firstResponder status as soon as editing begins? Also, note that the call to `-becomeFirstResponder` is superfluous -- the textField would have to be firstResponder if it got either of these delegate messages.

Comment: Because I am trying to make a DatePicker appear in place of the keyboard.

Comment: I see the date on this comment is super old, but if anybody is looking for this similar behaviour - just assign the date picker to the text field's .inputView property

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before resigning firstResponder status, the textField makes a callback to its own `-canResignFirstResponder` method, which returns `NO` if the textField is currently in an edit session. You can implement `-textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` delegate method to return `NO` if you want to prevent the editing session from beginning.

Answer (score 7):

This is years back, but needing something identical and this answer being at the top of my search results, I ended up playing and came up with this:

```
[myTextField performSelector:@selector(resignFirstResponder)
                  withObject:nil
                  afterDelay:0
 ];
```